# Из файла input.txt считайте строку символов S. Число символов, входящих в строку S, не более 255.Результаты вычислений запишите в файл output.txt

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
ifstream in("input.txt");
ofstream out;
out.open("output.txt");
char line[255];//Буферная переменная
int s;
if (!in.is_open()) // если файл не открыт
cout « "Файл не найден!\n"; // сообщить об этом
else
{
while (in.getline(line, 255)) // считали строку
{
for (s = 0; s < strlen(line); s++)
if (line[s] == 255)
line[s] = 0;
else
line[s] = line[s] + 1;
out « line « endl;
}
out.close();
}
}
```

Для считанной строки S определите сумму входящих в эту строку целых чисел
Это надо добавить но я не знаю куда и что вводить.Помогите плиз

Answer (score 0):

1. По условию файл может содержать 255 символов, поэтому `char line[256]`
2. Каждый раз вы инициализируете массив новой строкой ( while
   (in.getline(line, 255))), а надо весь файл читать в массив. Поэтому
   нужно добавить в массив вновь прочитанную строку.
   В данном случаи, когда мы точно знаем, что количество прочитанных символов не превышает размер массива можно, например, так:

   ```
   char* p = line;
   while (in.getline(p, 255))
       p = line + strlen(line);
   ```

Но вам нужно еще и анализировать содержимое файла _ найти числа, поэтому лучше прочитать по символу.

- Если этот символ `-` или `+`, то смотреть следующий символ(in.peek())
  является числом? Если да, то выполнить `read_add_write`( читать из файла число, добавить к `sum`,
  (где `int sum = 0` заранее объявлен) с учетом знака и записать строковое представление числа в массив(не знаю зачем в массив, если можно сразу в файл)).
- Если прочитанный символ уже число, тогда положить обратно в буфер (
  in.unget()) и выполнить `read_add_write`. Иначе просто записать в
  массив(файл)

.